# What is the difference between the ItemTouchHelper.Callback methods onChildDraw and onChildDrawOver?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

The documentation is identical of these two methods:

- [ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onChildDraw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20boolean))
- [ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDrawOver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onChildDrawOver(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20boolean))

Should any, both or a specific one be overridden when extending this class and you want to edit how children are drawn? What is the difference? What are the / examples of different use cases? Is the difference similar to the difference between these methods?

- [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration#onDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State))
- [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration#onDrawOver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#onDrawOver(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](http://android.xsoftlab.net/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html):

> ...Most of the time, you only need to override onChildDraw but due to limitations of platform prior to Honeycomb, you may need to implement onChildDrawOver as well...

So it's a matter of the API level you are targeting. I think nowadays you should almost always implement just `onChildDraw` unless your app runs on pre-Honeycomb as well.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) it says more or less the same, hadn't spotted that yet! Thanks!