# Issue with RecyclerView Item Swipe Animation

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working on an Android app that involves RecyclerView and swipe-to-dismiss functionality. While implementing the swipe-to-show-options animation, I encountered a peculiar issue.

Here's the code snippet for my custom swipe-to-show-options handling:

```
override fun onChildDrawOver(
        c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float,
        actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
        val isCanceled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive
        if (isCanceled) {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, false)
            return
        }

        if (viewHolder is OrderDetailProductsAdapter.OrderProductItemViewHolder) {
            val binding = LayoutHistoryDetailItemBinding.bind(itemView)
            binding.apply {
                getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, this.itemHistoryDetailMainView, dX / 2, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that this code doesn't scroll the view to half of the screen as intended. However, when I use the following code, which invokes the superclass's onChildDraw method, it works as expected:

```
super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX / 2, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
```

I'm looking to understand why the custom implementation doesn't produce the desired result while the default onChildDraw method does. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are two similar methods of [`onChildDraw`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDraw(android.graphics.Canvas,androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,float,float,int,boolean)) and [`onChildDrawOver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDrawOver(android.graphics.Canvas,androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,float,float,int,boolean)).

It seems that `onChildDrawOver` exists for the sake of compatibility on platforms prior to L (cf. *[What is the difference between the ItemTouchHelper.Callback methods onChildDraw and onChildDrawOver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47925938/3501958)*).

I think your code overrides just `onChildDrawOver` but `onChileDraw`, and the default (super class) `onChildDraw` is still alive.

I would suggest just avoid touching `onChildDrawOver` and make sure to utilize **`onChileDraw`** only.

Comment: That actually worked, Thanks, however I am unable to click on buttons in bottom view.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar That may be another type of problem. Please post it as a new question.